# Check null within chain of object accessing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

How Can I check null for each object I am using in below chain?

```
forensicId =  Message.Events.SMS.SMS_Mappings.FirstOrDefault().Bug.ForensicId;
```

More details: I want to access ForensicId from (tables/Proxies loaded by entity framework) BUG which is part of a SMS_Mappings and SMS_Mappings are again part of some table.

Is there any way where I can check if Message is not null or of events are not null and SMS is not null and so on within a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `forensicId =  Message?.Events?.SMS?.SMS_Mappings?.FirstOrDefault()?.Bug?.ForensicId;` It returns null if any object in chain is null or `ForensicId` value if everything is ok. [There](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/) is a nice article about such scenarios